# change dicom image's window width and window level

Tags: linux, vtk, dicom, dcmtk, qvtkwidget

Recently, I am working on process dicom image。I don't know how to change the WWWL of a dicom image. Also, I use dcmtk to convert dicom image to bmp and show it(I didn't use vtk to show the image). I really don't know if that is correct. 

I want to know the algorithm which can help me change the dicom image's window width and window level automatically. I didn't find the corresponding algorithm while I was using dcmtk.

thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the values of Window Center and Width (aka VOI transformation or windowing) manually, you can use [DicomImage::setWindow()](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html#aaf04c69ad334cb6ca01502d90e684217) for this purpose. If you want to specify an automatically computed min-max window, you could use [DicomImage::setMinMaxWindow()](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html#a8600a76ba5ba76bda729704098464f87).